# Vagrant cant reach server in browser on macOS High Sierra

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I've been able to setup a number of local servers using different boxes; `laravel/homestead` & `ubuntu/xenial64`. These seem to spin up fine and when I run `vagrant shh` I can connect to the server without any issue. It even seems to be syncing the folder as expected into the `/vagrant` directory.

**But when I try to load this (http://127.0.0.1/) into the browser, I just receive a "This site can’t be reached" error in Chrome.**

By default the `Vagrantfile` looks like this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
end
```

I've previously been using Mamp Pro (which is still installed but not active) on my macOS High Sierra machine. So I don't think there is any port conflicts or anything like that.

But in case this is the issue, I have tried setting up a specific IP address like so

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "55.55.55.5"
```

I've also tried defining different ports for the host

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 4567, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
```

I must be missing something in the configuration, but [according to the documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/getting-started/networking.html) this should work. Any suggestions?

Just FYI, I've installed VirtualBox and Vagrant (using Homebrew) and am using Vagrant Manager to oversee the boxes.

Comment: If I setup a `scotch/box` VM following their docs, that works fine... I've (somewhat blindly) tried to mimic the `Vagrantfile` configuration and this doesn't work on any other boxes (e.g. `ubuntu/xenial64`).

Comment: Why do you think `http://127.0.0.1/` should respond?

Comment: Because in the docs when setting a new host port (to `4567`) the URL is `http://127.0.0.1:4567`

Comment: I'm not fussed what IP should go in the URL... Just wanna see it working lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just installed default ubuntu OS.

You dont have a web server running .. You can install Apache or nginx, and make sure you start the server, then only after that you can access it.

The scotch/box vagrant VM has a set of provisionner that installs all the server for you hence this is running fine.

Comment: Oh wow... what an oversight! With this in mind is Scotch a good box to start with, or are there others that are recommended?

Comment: As an after thought... would the case have been the same with `laravel/homestead` just I had the same issue there? And given it's popularity I'd assume this will have Apache (etc) installed

Comment: Right ˋlaravel/homestead` would work ootb as web server is installed on VM

Comment: Is the a specific port configuration that needs to be defined then? Just on the default `vagrant init` setup, I experience the same issue as with  `ubuntu/xenial64`